# Group by and Count character values R

Tags: dplyr, group-by, count

I need to count how many orders is per date and how many "yes" and "no" for each date.
How can I from the data frame like this:

```
  order <- c("order_1",  "order_2","order_3","order_4","order_5")
  check <- c("yes",  "no","no","yes","yes")
  df1 <-  data.frame(order,  date,check )
  df1


    order   date      check
1 order_1 2020-01-01   yes
2 order_2 2020-01-01    no
3 order_3 2020-01-01    no
4 order_4 2020-01-02   yes
5 order_5 2020-01-02   yes
```

Get table like this:

```
    date      number_orders  yes  no
1 2020-01-01       3          1    2
2 2020-01-02       2          0    0

´´´
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by adding your `yes` and `no` columns to the dataframe. Let `yes` be true whenever `check == 'yes'` and false otherwise, and let `no` be true whenever `check == 'no'` and false otherwise.

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(yes = (check == 'yes'), no = (check == 'no'))
```

Now group by date and use `summarize()` to count up the number of orders. You can take advantage of the fact that `TRUE` evaluates to 1 and `FALSE` evaluates to 0 to sum over the `yes` and `no` columns.

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(number_orders = n(),
         yes = sum(yes),
         no = sum(no))
```

The full code can be written as one line with dplyr's pipe operation.

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(yes = (check == 'yes'), no = (check == 'no')) %>%
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(number_orders = n(),
         yes = sum(yes),
         no = sum(no))
```